# Как происходит преобразование к source character set при включении файлов?

Tags: c++, c, кодировка, gcc, include

У меня есть `A.cpp` файл в кодировке `X`, в него включается хедер `B.h` с кодировкой `Y`, в этот хедер `B.h` включается хедер `C.h` с кодировкой `Z`. Что происходит с кодировками файлов при таком включении для компилятора `gcc` с опцией `-finput-charset=X`?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что сначала, т.к. `#include` выполняется рекурсивно, байты `C.h` приводятся из `Z` в `Y`, а потом байты `B.h` с включенным `C.h` из `Y` преобразуются в `X`? Либо же `Z` сразу приводится к `X`? Или преобразований кодировок нет вовсе? Что тогда означает mapping/convert к source character set?

[The individual bytes of the source code file are mapped (in implementation-defined manner) to the characters of the basic source character set.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

[The files input to CPP might be in any character set at all. CPP’s very first action, before it even looks for line boundaries, is to convert the file into the character set it uses for internal processing.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets)

По какому алгоритму происходит этот mapping и могут ли быть ошибки при нём?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опция `-finput-charset` указывает кодировку входящих файлов. Все эти файлы уже должны быть сохранены в этой кодировке. Никакого преобразования кодировки не происходит. Если у файлов разная кодировка, то получается винегрет.

Comment: Что тогда означает эта фраза *"The individual bytes of the source code file are mapped (in implementation-defined manner) to the characters of the basic source character set ."* [отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)?

Comment: И *"The files input to CPP might be in any character set at all. CPP’s very first action, before it even looks for line boundaries, is to convert the file into the character set it uses for internal processing."* [отсюда](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets)?

Comment: Эти фразы означают, что символы из файлов преобразуются в ту форму, с которой работает компилятор.

Comment: А обсуждаемая опция задает, какая кодировка подразумевается в входящих файлах.

Comment: Где-нибудь описано поведение программы при моём сценарии? ill-formed? implementation-defined?

Comment: Ничего хорошего явно не произойдет. Храните все файлы в utf8

Comment: И рад бы, но мне надо включить сторонние хедер-онли библиотеки в windows-1251 в мой сорс с UTF-8, а изменить кодировку этих библиотек не могу

Comment: @Ruslan, а какая разница, 1251 или utf8? Там что, имена переменных кириллицей написаны?

Comment: @Qwertiy Строковые литералы в таком случае запросто могут побиться.

Comment: @user7860670, строковые литералы в h-файлах? А они там зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy А почему бы строковым литералам не быть в .h файлах? А если библиотека заголовочная, то и нет никакого другого места им быть.

Comment: @user7860670, не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну например там реализована функция и в ней написано `fopen("unicode file path"`