# Что происходит, если файл А включает файл Б с другой кодировкой?

Tags: c++, c, кодировка, gcc, include

Что происходит, если `A.c` включает `B.h` и у этих файлов разные кодировки? Где-нибудь описано поведение компилятора/программы в таком случае? Зависит от реализации, невалидная программа или что-то другое?

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-source-character-set-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2 ?

Comment: @KoVadim там не ответили на конкретно этот вопрос в комментах, поэтому задал отдельно

Comment: ну подумайте, что такое include? это просто копипаста файла. Все. А как потом байтики сложаться - вот так и будет. Да, там есть разные краевые случаи, связанные с интерпретацией многобайтовых кодировок для символов, которые оказались на "границе", но в целом никаких проблем

Comment: @KoVadim вот тут вы уже не совсем правы. Например, куда девается BOM, просто *"копипастится"*?

Comment: А я вот взял и проверил. А результат прикольный. Файл читается согласно выставленному finputencoding. Если он utf8, то bom успешно выбрасывается. Если же кодировка cp1251, то они остаются, правда эскейптся.  То есть, да, ридер читает согласно установленным правилам входной кодировки и результат копипаститься по месту. И если чуточку подумать, то все правильно, они именно "копипаститься"( да, в кавычках, будет наиболее правильно)

Comment: @KoVadim, наверное это windows-специфичноый вопрос? У меня в linux никаких BOM в начале файлов нет

Comment: не знаю. но я делал все на линуксе. BOM добавил вручную, что бы он гарантированно был